# Ionic Capacitor: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for ... :Unknown Error

Tags: ionic-framework, android-emulator, capacitor

I cannot debug my application from my `Android Emulator`. I do not know what was happening because before it was running fine and can be debugged.

These are the error I got from the `chrome://inspect`:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/bundle.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/main.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/3.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/53.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/51.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/49.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/39.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/16.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/33.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/20.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/22.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/42.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/47.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/15.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/24.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/44.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/7.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/29.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/45.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/41.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/9.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/21.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://192.168.100.31:8100/static/js/25.chunk.js.map: Unknown error
```

I cannot set the breakpoints in any of my `.ts` source file.

If I open `http://192.168.100.31:8100` from browser, I can debug it perfectly, but not if I run it on Android Emulator. Also it works fine if I run my application on a real device, it can be debugged in the real device, but not in emulator.

I suppose there is something wrong with the connection between browser and emulator.

Please help I need to debug my application inside my emulator.

---

### CONFIG

`ionic.config.json`:

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
  },
  "type": "react"
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
, "../StoreApp/src/helpers/util.tsx"  ]
}
```

Comment: I would rule out Ionic and Capacitor or Cordova. Because this happends to me as well, but I'm using Cordova instead of Capacitor. Sometimes it just works, but 99% of the time, it doesn't. I have no idea why. I don't use ionic serve anymore. I modified it so that ng serve works directly on emulator, however, it's the same issue. Seeing how you have the same issues, I would rule out Ionic and Capacitor or Cordova.

Comment: "Sourcemap can't be found errors" will not prevent the app from working or break the emulator, so the error is something else.  Are you able to open the `ionic serve` endpoint in the emulator's browser?

Answer (score 0):

Using Ionic and Capacitor CLI commands worked for me.

```
Ionic : 7
Capacitor: 5
Angular: 16
```

For More Detail on Ionic Commands

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/build

For more detail on CLI Commands

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cli/commands/copy

Build web assets and prepare your app for any platform targets

--source-map: Output source maps

```
ionic build --source-map
```

Copy the web app build and Capacitor configuration file into the native platform project

--inline: After syncing, all JS source maps will be inlined allowing for debugging an Android Web View in Chromium based browsers.

```
npx cap copy android --inline
```

Build web assets and prepare your app for any platform targets

```
npx cap run android
```